# How do I get more than 500 contact lists on Android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to get more than 500 contact list as string in Android 6.0 and above. Below is a code that works perfectly. But if the contact list is more than 100, the application hangs. I can see people on logcat when I want to get 500 contact list. However, the user cannot do anything in the application. And the application may crash. I think this is related to the forage. I've been dealing with this problem for five days. But I didn't get any performance results. Any help, I'd appreciate it.

> My Activity;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Cursor cursor;
    ArrayList<String> vCard;
    String vfile;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        vfile = "Contacts" + System.currentTimeMillis() +".vcf";

        getVcardString();
}

private void getVcardString() {

        vCard = new ArrayList<String>();

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor!=null&&cursor.getCount()>0){

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for(int i =0;i<cursor.getCount();i++){


                try {
                    get(cursor);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        else{

            ViewAlertDashboard02();
        }

    }

    public void get(Cursor cursor) throws IOException {

        String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);

        AssetFileDescriptor fd = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();

        byte[] buf = readBytes(fis);

        try {

            fis.read(buf);

            vcardstring = new String(buf);
            vCard.add(vcardstring);

            Log.d("Vcard",vcardstring);


        } catch (Exception e1){

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        // and then we can return your byte array.
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

> My LogCat;

```
    >     08-17 14:56:44.984 3530-3289/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.024 3530-32650/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.054 3530-4755/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.084 3530-4546/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.124 3530-4513/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.154 3530-4517/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.184 3530-7059/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.204 3530-3548/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.234 3530-13626/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.264 3530-3290/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.284 3530-3289/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.314 3530-3291/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.334 3530-3550/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.364 3530-3882/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.384 3530-32650/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.424 3530-3292/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.454 3530-4755/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.484 3530-26421/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.504 3530-4546/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.534 3530-3293/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.554 3530-4513/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.584 3530-4517/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.604 3530-7059/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.634 3530-3548/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.664 3530-13626/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.684 3530-3290/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.714 3530-3289/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.744 3530-3291/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.764 3530-3550/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.794 3530-3882/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.814 3530-32650/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.844 3530-3292/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.864 3530-4755/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.894 3530-26421/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.924 3530-4546/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.944 3530-3293/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.974 3530-4513/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:45.994 3530-4517/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.024 3530-7059/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.064 3530-3548/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.094 3530-13626/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.134 3530-3290/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.164 3530-3289/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.204 3530-3291/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.264 3530-3550/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.294 3530-3882/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.314 3530-3292/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.334 3530-4755/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.364 3530-26421/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.384 3530-4546/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.404 3530-3293/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.434 3530-4513/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.464 3530-3548/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.484 3530-13626/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.514 3530-7059/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.544 3530-32650/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.564 3530-4517/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.594 3530-3882/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.614 3530-4755/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.644 3530-3289/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.674 3530-4546/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.714 3530-3293/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.744 3530-3291/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.784 3530-3290/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.814 3530-3292/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.844 3530-26421/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.874 3530-3550/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.904 3530-4513/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.924 3530-3548/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.954 3530-13626/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:46.974 3530-7059/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.014 3530-32650/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.044 3530-4517/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.064 3530-3882/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.094 3530-4755/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.114 3530-3289/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.144 3530-4546/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.174 3530-3293/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.204 3530-3291/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.234 3530-3290/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.264 3530-3292/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.284 3530-26421/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.324 3530-3550/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.354 3530-4513/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.394 3530-3548/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.424 3530-13626/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.464 3530-7059/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.494 3530-32650/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.524 3530-4517/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.564 3530-3882/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.594 3530-4755/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.644 3530-3289/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.694 3530-4546/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.724 3530-3293/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.784 3530-3291/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.814 3530-3290/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.854 3530-3292/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.914 3530-26421/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
    >     08-17 14:56:47.954 3530-3550/? E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
```

I have two problems with this code. My first problem is that it doesn't work well and the application may crash. My other problem is that if I have 500 people in my contact list, it shows more. I think the reason for this is that forcing the processor. I think it repeats a process more. Your experience and knowledge can be the solution for me. Thanks in advance.

**Note: This code works seamlessly up to 100 contact list on Android 4 and above and supports the latest versions of android. You can use it.**

Comment: Start by moving all of this I/O to a background thread.

Comment: Just use background thread for getting contact.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I created a background service and started it when a button was pressed. I'm trying to get the contact list in the background service, but again the application crashes and the application hangs. Could you please show me an example? Where am I doing wrong? @CommonsWare

Comment: "I created a background service and started it when a button was pressed" -- you do not need a service to use a background thread. "but again the application crashes" -- then ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where the [mcve] shows the stack trace from the crash and the code that triggered the crash. Your current question has "the application may crash", but you do not show a stack trace, so we have no way of knowing what is crashing and where. For example, you might be getting an `OutOfMemoryError` from trying to load the vCard data for every contact into memory at once.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm just learning things. I tried background thread the way you said. And everything's okay now. I mixed background thread with background service. Thank you for showing me this way. I learned something new and gained experience. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two big issues there:

1. Running long-running code on the UI thread
2. Mixing between querying over the `Phone.CONTENT_URI` and the `Contacts.CONTENT_URI`

For issue #1, you can change your `onCreate` code to the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vfile = "Contacts" + System.currentTimeMillis() +".vcf";

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getVcardString();
            }
    }).start();
}
```

For issue #2, the problem is that your main query is to get all the phones in the DB, and then go phone-by-phone and convert the contact relevant to that phone to a vcard. so if a single contact has multiple phones, you'll be adding the same contact multiple times.

I'm assuming you need only contacts with phones, so change your main query from:

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

to:

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1";
cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, null, null);
```

If the fixed code still crashes, it might be `OutOfMemoryError` post the exception stack here, there's some things you can improve.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer. I was able to correct my # 1 problem. The second problem continues. I tried your answer, but it didn't work. The contact list still looks pretty high. If there are 5 people in my contact list, it shows about twice as much. Can you suggest another answer? Why does he look so much like that?

Comment: sometimes you think you have 5 contacts but actually you might have 10, you can add a log for each cursor row with `Contacts._ID` and `Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME` to check which contacts is the code finding, and to make sure there are no duplicates. you can also add to your selection `Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1"` to filter to only visible contacts

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried it. But the list of contacts continues to look too much.

Comment: did you add the log? are you seeing 10 different contact-ids with 10 different display-names?

Comment: I did an experiment like this. I deleted the contact list and tried again. No one seems to have 9 people in the application but no one appears in the logcat. Then I added 2 different people. 11 people appear in the application but I see 2 people in the logcat.

I used this: String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1";
cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, null, null);

Comment: if you're seeing only 2 lines in the log that means the code only read 2 contacts, the fact you're seeing more contacts in the app might suggest a bug in a different part of the app. maybe add another log for `vcard.size()` when you finish iterating the cursor.

Comment: also, i would recommend switching from a for loop to a `while (cursor.moveToNext()) { ... }` loop (no need for moveToFirst)